# Call another function dart into the page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have one empty page with the app bar title and one function dart called the upload page. How can I call this function to the page? How to show the page with the upload function?

Another question is can flutter has a function to call a button to select the file from file explorer. After I clicked the button, it will navigate me to the file directory so I can upload my file to the page and the page will show which file I uploaded.

[Empty page][2]

**Upload Page.dart**

```
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth/Screens/Login/components/body.dart';

main() => runApp(UploadPage());

class UploadPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _App();
  }
}

class _App extends State<UploadPage> {
  String _fileName;
  String _path;
  Map<String, String> _paths;
  String _extension;
  bool _loadingPath = false;
  bool _multiPick = false;
  bool _hasValidMime = false;
  FileType _pickingType;
  TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() => _extension = _controller.text);
  }

  void _openFileExplorer() async {
    if (_pickingType != FileType.custom || _hasValidMime) {
      setState(() => _loadingPath = true);
      try {
        if (_multiPick) {
          _path = null;
          _paths = await FilePicker.getMultiFilePath(
              type: _pickingType, allowedExtensions: [_extension]);
        } else {
          _paths = null;
          _paths = await FilePicker.getMultiFilePath(
              type: _pickingType, allowedExtensions: [_extension]);
        }
      } on PlatformException catch (e) {
        print("Unsupported operation" + e.toString());
      }
      if (!mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        _loadingPath = false;
        _fileName = _path != null
            ? _path.split('/').last
            : _paths != null
                ? _paths.keys.toString()
                : '...';
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("FilePickerApp"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(
              child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, bottom: 20.0),
                child: new RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () => _openFileExplorer(),
                  child: new Text("Open file picker"),
                ),
              ),
              new Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => _loadingPath
                    ? Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                        child: const CircularProgressIndicator())
                    : _path != null || _paths != null
                        ? new Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
                            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.50,
                            child: new Scrollbar(
                                child: new ListView.separated(
                              itemCount: _paths != null && _paths.isNotEmpty
                                  ? _paths.length
                                  : 1,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                final bool isMultiPath =
                                    _paths != null && _paths.isNotEmpty;
                                final String name = 'File $index: ' +
                                    (isMultiPath
                                        ? _paths.keys.toList()[index]
                                        : _fileName ?? '...');
                                final path = isMultiPath
                                    ? _paths.values.toList()[index].toString()
                                    : _path;

                                return new ListTile(
                                  title: new Text(
                                    name,
                                  ),
                                  subtitle: new Text(path),
                                );
                              },
                              separatorBuilder:
                                  (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                                      new Divider(),
                            )),
                          )
                        : new Container(),
              ),
            ],
          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yda1c.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMb0P.png
```

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your question.. If you wanna show another page you can use material route.

Comment: Hi , my question is I have a empty page with a app bar title(“load excel file “) but how can I put in whatever function I want in the page ?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to pass parameter to another page?